# Design an algorithm that prints all natural numbers less than or equal N

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this algorithm with basic python, due to the fact that I'm only in my first computer science class in my freshman year at college. What are your recommendations on how I should go about creating this algorithm? I'm open minded to anything! Excited to hear back. Thanks.

Comment: Algorithm? Isn't this just running a loop?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose so. Sorry, just going by it as my professor wrote the question. "Design an algorithm that prints all natural numbers less than or equal N."

Comment: please define "natural numbers". (if it just means integers, well, look at 'for' and 'range')

Comment: Yes, I was confused about natural numbers as well. I believe the professor just meant integers, he's not exactly great at communicating...

Comment: Take some time to work your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) it will give you an idea of what tools are available to solve your problems.  Many times the best place to start designing an algorithm is on paper with a pencil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop

```
N = 10
for i in range(1,N+1):
    print(i)
```

You can also use a `while` loop

```
N = 10
i = 1
while i <= N:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

(Assuming natural numbers means positive integers)

Comment: No assuming - The set of Natural numbers are values greater than 0 i.e. counting numbers.

Comment: @Chinny84 idk some places might refer to 0 as a natural number